# PHP check array object key value without using loop/foreach

Tags: php, arrays, arrayobject

Just to learn more techniques in PHP , I'm so used in loop foreach and I want to find some other ways on how to check an array object. Let's say if we have a result something like this:

```
 Array
(
    [0] =; stdClass Object
        (
            [gallery_id] => 38
            [artist_id] => 58
            [title] => Appearances
            [description] => Appearances
            [photo_file] => 
            [status] => 1
            [insert_timestamp] => 2014-08-07 03:27:23
            [update_timestamp] => 2014-08-07 15:26:24
            [url] => talents/58/photos/38/Appearances
            [position] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gallery_id] => 36
            [artist_id] => 58
            [title] => Endorsements
            [description] => Endorsements
            [photo_file] => 
            [status] => 1
            [insert_timestamp] => 2014-08-07 03:17:28
            [update_timestamp] => 2015-01-13 15:50:09
            [url] => talents/58/photos/36/Endorsements
            [position] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gallery_id] => 34
            [artist_id] => 58
            [title] => Magazine Covers
            [description] => Magazine Covers
            [photo_file] => 
            [status] => 1
            [insert_timestamp] => 2014-08-07 02:54:27
            [update_timestamp] => 2015-01-13 15:50:10
            [url] => talents/58/photos/34/Magazine-Covers
            [position] =&gt; 2
        )
)
```

I know we can do something like this to check a value in the object:

```
$myFlag = 2;

foreach($objArr as $obj){

  if($obj->position == $myFlag){

    return true;
  }

}
```

But is there a way to check it without using a loop? A more efficient way, coz I feel whenever I use this(most of the time) , It's not that efficient and somehow takes time to process.

Comment: "Please ignore &gt as =>" --- any reason why you don't want to make it readable yourself?

Comment: "It's not that efficient and somehow takes time to process" --- if you need to find something in an array - you have to iterate over it. So it's always `O(n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using array_filter with closure.

```
$myFlag = 2;
$target = array_filter($objArr, function($elem) use($myFlag){
        return $elem->position === $myFlag;
    });

print_r($target);
```

result is ...

```
Array
(
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gallery_id] => 34
            [artist_id] => 58
            [title] => Magazine Covers
            [description] => Magazine Covers
            [photo_file] =>
            [status] => 1
            [insert_timestamp] => 2014-08-07 02:54:27
            [update_timestamp] => 2015-01-13 15:50:10
            [url] => talents/58/photos/34/magazine-covers
            [position] => 2
        )

)
```